# how to compare schema and data of two different databases

Tags: database, comparison, schema, procedure

**how to compare schema and data of two different databases and synchronize the latest changes in target database through c shrap Code. Note: i'm working on  Desktop Application with Sql Server 2014**

Explanation:
i'm working with Desktop application on visual studio 2013 and sql server 2014.
i want my application to work with local database, but after a specific time i want to sync new entries OR new schema changes in remote database having the exact same schema as local database. I want solution in c# code. may be stored procedure can also helpful.